How to manage (read & write) variables values between pipeline and shared libraries?
I have a Declarative Pipeline that is increasing in size, so I want to split the logic using shared libraries.
But I´m facing some issues because I must share some values between them and I can´t find the way to do it.
Here are some examples of what I need to do:

I have different branches in my git repo and different environments where the job could work, so I have several variables that are dynamically populated based on the current execution requirements to store the right branch name, server name,... I need to expose that information with the library methods to execute the logic in the right targets.
I also need library methods can change some pipeline variables values to reflect the results of different actions done in those methods. Ex: to allow a future action in the pipeline to know which specific components were affected.

Is there some way to solve this issue? I´m sure there must be something because the global/local variables scope is a foundation for coding, but I can´t find anything.
I tried using environment variables, but they can only be written in the environment clause. I know you can change them using withEnv or other environment clauses, but you cannot change the value and access to the new value in a different place, so they are more like constants that can be used in the piece of code they are populated.
So I can access to environment variables with the value when they were defined, but I can´t change that value based on the current execution conditions (ex: if it must be executed in branch A or B).

Finally, I included multiple variables as input parameters for each method, and they return multiple values.
It is not the best option for me, as I must pass around 10-12 variables for input and 4-5 for output, even when most of them are needed for input and output, so if I could pass them by reference to update them directly, or even better if I could access external vars inside of each method, it would be perfect, but at least it is working as required.
Thanks for your help.

Making libraries in Jenkins is no different than making them in any other language. Library methods will not have access to the scope of the pipeline unless you pass variables as arguments and whatever you want to change should be returned from the library methods and assigned in the pipeline.
env is the kind of global scope that is free for all and that's exactly why you shouldn't use it this way. But there is nothing in Jenkins that would stop you.

Thanks for your answer @iterokun, but I must pass and receive a long list of variables to the library.
Is there no way to make them available for read/write in the library without passing them, but making them global or something like that? In that way, I don´t require to pass all of them as input for the library during the call, and return an array or something like that to return multiple values at once
I can´t find anyt documentation or examples googleing

Find logical structure to those variables, make them into a config object (or map, if there is too much flux), pass the config object, don't modify it. Returning multiple values from methods is easy, Groovy supports multiple assignment. Global scope is bad, settled science :)
